# CrashlyticsInitProvider skipping initialization OR Settings request failed

Tags: android, crashlytics-android

I have a project which had crashlytics, fabric or whatever somewhere in the past. Now, when I'm trying to set it up once again and add this to manifest:

```
<meta-data
     android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
     android:value="my_key_which_came_from_previous_developer" 
/>
```

I get the "CrashlyticsInitProvider skipping initialization" without any detailed description.

But if I remove the code above and add

```
<meta-data
    android:name="my_key_which_came_from_previous_developer"
    tools:node="remove" 
/>
```

I get it somehow initialized BUT have the new problem -

> I/System.out: [CDS][DNS]Unable to resolve host
>   "settings.crashlytics.com": No address associated with hostname
>
> E/Fabric: Settings request failed.

So it either receives the settings or initializes the crashlytics. What do I do? Is there a way to completely remove and reinstall crashlytics for my application?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in proguard turned on and not properly configured to work with crashlytics. If the minifyEnabled option was set to "true" it wouldn't receive setting on the initial run. Nevertheless, it worked fine sending results if installed *with* proguard enabled.